# Azure DevOps YAML pipelines specification of matrix through build variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got the following job:

```
- job: CB_Jobs
  displayName: CB jobs
  pool: server
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Libs: 
        Dir: 'src/hw/libs'
      Apps:
        Dir: 'src/hw/apps'
  steps:
```

Which is just specifying a list of directories. I need to be able to specify that list in a build variable (which is settable at queue time). This is possible in the non-YAML flow by specifying the job as multi-configuration with the name of the build variable as the Multipliers. How do I do this in YAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a JSON formatted string, and it will be parsed by Azure:

Example: (you might need to tweak the syntax)

In a previous job (JobA):

```
$json="{'job1': {'Work': 'work1'}, 'job2': {'Work': 'work2'}}"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$jobsToRunInParallel;isOutput=true]$json"
```

In the job to run in parallel:

```
matrix: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['jobsToRunInParallel'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
parameters:
  - name: Libs
    type: object
    default: []
jobs:
- job: CB_Jobs
  pool: server
  strategy:
    matrix:
       ${{ each Lib in parameters.Libs}}:
        ${{ Lib }}:
         Dir: ${{ Lib }}

You can access the variable Dir using $(Dir) in steps
```